# Should I use, this, self or something else for self identifiers in type definitions?

Tags: oop, f#

My guess is that "this" is more C#-ish and in F# it's better to use "self".

Are there any required/preferred coding guidelines?

Comment: An interesting question. As an observation, looking in `.fs` files installed with the most recent published F# build (1.9.7.8) - which includes the PowerPack - it uses `this` most often, but `self` in quite a few places as well, and occasionally even single-character names such as `x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to "this", "self", and "x", I have also seen "__" and "lowercaseenclosingclassname".

Comment: In my experience I use 'this' to be like C#, 'x' when brevity is desired, and '__' to indicate that the value isn't important.

Answer (score 2):

In many examples I've seen people are using just x. In my own code started with this, but now I usually do x, because IMHO it makes the code somewhat more readable