# F# instance syntax

Tags: f#

What indicator do you use for member declaration in F#? I prefer

```
member a.MethodName
```

*this* is to many letters and *x* is used otherwise.

Comment: Also see other answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793484/should-i-use-this-self-or-something-else-for-self-identifiers-in-type-definitio

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I do almost always use `x` as the name of *this* instance. There is no logic behind that, aside from the fact that it is shorter than other options.

The options that I've seen are:

```
member x.Foo     // Simply use (short) 'x' everywhere
member ls.Foo    // Based on type name as Benjol explains
member this.Foo  // Probably comfortable for C# developers
member self.Foo  // I'm not quite sure where this comes from!
member __.Foo    // Double underscore to resemble 'ignore pattern' 
                 // (patterns are not allowed here, but '__' is identifier)
```

The option based on the type name makes some sense (and is good when you're nesting object expressions inside a type), but I think it could be quite difficult to find reasonable two/three abbreviation for every type name.

Comment: There's always 'me.Foo', after VB.NET. I use either 'x' or 'this'.

Comment: I use `this` so I don't scare off the C# programmers looking at my code.

Comment: `self` seems to be used in the OCaml community. See [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual005.html#ss:reference-to-self). Also Python, Delphi, Smalltalk. Though I guess OCaml should be the influential one here.

Answer (score 3):

Don't have a system. Wonder if I should have one, and I am sure there will be a paradigm with its own book some day soon. I tend to use first letter(s) of the type name, like Benjol.

This is a degree of freedom in F# we could clearly do without. :)

Comment: a signifies "type" in most fp languages. I wonder if it is ok to use for instance members

Comment: @napoleonss I don't know most fp languages, but you have 'a (or '<any identifier>) to signify type in F#; in ML you also have ''a etc. - a by itself is a normal identifier which you can use however you wish.

Comment: Yes, it just appears more coherent

Comment: @napoleonss In which case you'll need to resort to one of the other 25 letters of the (English) alphabet, or combinations thereof. Which leaves you with your original dilemma.

Comment: "This is a degree of freedom in F# we could clearly do without." Very true.

Comment: You can usually do without the extra degree of freedom, but it comes in handy when creating an object expression within a member.  That way, you can refer to the outer instance and the inner instance using different identifiers.

Comment: Yep. Was being facetious. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use some kind of initials which represent the type so:

```
type LaserSimulator = 
    member ls.Fire() =
```

Answer (score 1):

I largely tend to use `self.MethodName`, for the single reason that `self` represents the current instance by convention in the other language I use most: Python. Come to think of it, I used Delphi for some time and they have `self` as well instead of `this`.

I have been trying to convert to a `x.MethodName` style, similar to the two books I am learning from: *Real World Functional Programming* and *Expert F#*. So far I am not succeeding, mainly because referring to `x` rather than `self` (or `this`) in the body of the method still confuses me.

I guess what I am saying is that there should be a meaningful convention. Using `this` or `self` has already been standardised by other languages. And I personally don't find the three letter economy to be that useful.

Answer (score 1):

Since I work in the .NET world, I tend to use "this" on the assumption that most of the .NET people who encounter F# will understand its meaning.  Of course, the other edge of that sword is that they might get the idea that "this" is the required form.

.NET self-documentation concerns aside, I think I would prefer either: "x" in general, or -- like Benjol -- some abbreviation of the class name (e.g. "st" for SuffixTrie, etc.).

Comment: both IronPython, IronRuby, VB.NET, F# and more are .NET language and neither uses 'this'. Did you me C# world?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I meant C#. Here I am a long time advocate of multi-language programming under .NET and I find myself hoist by my own petard! Lol.  Most of the .NET programmers I encounter *are* C# programmers, but it's bad form of me to automatically assume so -- especially when I'm such a proponent of F#.

Answer (score 0):

The logic I use is this: if I'm not using the instance reference inside the member definition, I use a double underscore ('__'), a la let-binding expressions. If I am referencing the instance inside the definition (which I don't do often), I tend to use 'x'.

Comment: If you are not using the instance reference, wouldn't your member definition be better off being static? Would be the correct syntax for this semantics, and would eliminate the instance identifier altogether.

Comment: @Alexander: Not necessarily. For example, a value is passed to a constructor, and exposed (possibly after applying some trivial function) as a read-only property. There's no need to access the instance in the definition of the member. Even if I stored the ctor's input in a private let-binding, I still wouldn't need to access the instance-identifying symbol... and the data is still relevant to the instance not the type.

Comment: @pblasucci Can't see the case you mention, but just thought myself that you may be using other instance methods from within the 'nameless' one, so yes, I jumped to a wrong conclusion here... (can see your text now, some glitch with the JavaScript here, it seems; so yes, there is more than one case where this makes sense).

Comment: @pblasucci _ seems interesting and coherent with fp convention. I 'll try out with a. for instance access

Comment: Does this actually work?  For me, `type T = member _.Method() = 1` doesn't compile, while `type T = member a.Method() = 1` does...

Comment: @kvb: No, I think it doesn't work (it has to be name, not a pattern). I've seen people using double underscore as a workaround for this.

Comment: Apologies. I mis-typed. I meant double underscore ('__'). Sorry. My bad! I've edited my response accordingly.